# post method with python and html connected to mysql gives 405 page not found error?

Tags: python, html, mysql

I'm making a html website, and I need to save user credentials in a mysql, i tried to do it through php but I wasn't ready for that, so I used the flask framework, and tried to use a POST method to save the user credentials through python to the database. but I keep getting the same 405 error, "This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405
", what do i do? html:

```
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
   

   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    button1 = document.getElementById("subm");
    console.log("Hi");
var match = false;
    var check = function() {
    

      // to check if passwords match

if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
  document.getElementById('confirm_password').value && match == true) {
  document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'green';
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'matching';
  button1.style.display = "block";
} else if(document.getElementById('password').value !=
  document.getElementById('confirm_password').value && match == true) {
  document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'red';
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'not matching';
  button1.style.display = "none";
}
    //to make sure that the password is over 0 characters
const pass = document.getElementById('password').value
if (pass.length > 9) {
  document.getElementById('message1').style.color = 'green';
  document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML = 'password over 10 characters';
  
  match = true;
} else {
  document.getElementById('message1').style.color = 'red';
  document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML = 'Password Has to be at least 10 characters';
  button1.style.display = "none";
}    
}
document.getElementById("password").addEventListener("input", check);
document.getElementById("confirm_password").addEventListener("input", check);

});  
      
  </script>
  <style>
      * {box-sizing: border-box}

  
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=email], input[type=password], input[type=username] {




<div class="container">
  
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
  <button class = "havac" onclick="window.location.href='login.html'"><a class = "havtxt">Have an account? Press here</a></button>
  <hr>
  <form  method="post" action="index.py">

    <label class = "email" for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    <label class = "email" for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input name = "username" type = "username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>

    <label class = "password">password :
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" onkeyup='check();' />
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class = "password">confirm password:
      <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password"  onkeyup='check();' /> 
      <span id='message'></span>
      <span id='message1'></span>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input  class = "verif" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
    </label>

    <button onclick="window.location.href='termsandprivacy.html'"> <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p></button>

    <div class="clearfix">
      
      <button name = "submit" id = "subm" type="submit" class="signupbtn"  >[ E N T E R]</button>
      
      
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    username = request.form['username']
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']

    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='///',
        database='///'
    )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    val = (username, email, password)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()

    return 'Success!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I slashed out the password and database for safety

I tried to get the user credentials through python and expected for it to save in the mysql database